# print summary from dominanceAnalysis to latex in R

Tags: r, latex, lm, xtable, stargazer

I have conduceted dominance analysis:

```
library(dominanceanalysis)
  lm.attitude<-lm(rating~.,attitude)
  da.attitude<-dominanceAnalysis(lm.attitude)
summary(da.attitude)
```

how can i print this results to latex? something like this (ignore highlighting)

[image]

Comment: What is precisely your problem? Doing an array in LaTeX? Doing this specific array? Highlighting some values? An what are your current attempts?

Comment: my specific problem is writing the code in R that produce latex output. There is a package called stargazer, which is frequently used but only support specific object types (like lm).... a am looking fro another package that can print latex output of any type of object

Comment: I am trying to avoid to create the array in latex, as that would mean that i have to copy and paste all the values... but if there is no other option i would take that as well

Comment: I have no specific knowledge on tools associated with R. But if it is possible to output something similar to csv, you can use the datatool package to generate a latex table without copy-paste from this csv file.